# Hibernate OneToOne and lazy fetch issue

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading, one-to-one

I have model named Article and a model named Shop, and the relation is ManyToMany

Article

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name="shop_article",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="article_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="shop_id")
)
private Set<Shop> shops = new HashSet<Shop>();
```

Shop:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="shops", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<Article>();
```

And my Shop have relation OneToOne with Page

Shop:

```
@OneToOne( fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
@JoinColumn(name = "page_id")
private Page page;
```

it's works well except for one detail
When i try add new Article, in my view i use

```
<form:select path="shops" multiple="true"
            items="${shops}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
```

my shops object fetching all Pages relation. But when i sysout shops in controller or remove form:select from view, Pages not fetching, is the correct.

Where is the problem? 
What part of my code to paste to help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a lazy loading problem. I don't really understand your model, but do you really ever want a shop without referencing a page? Probably not, right? So, change the `fetch` to be `EAGER`, and if you're using hibernate then add `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)`.

Comment: you do not understand in my model? Perhaps I joined something wrong? I want select only id and name from Shop, to do select list in view i dont want fetch any relations object. <br /> @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) - what is it doing?